# NameError: name 'test_scores' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import math
import numpy as np

test_scores[88,92,79,93,84]
print(np.mean(test_scores))
```

I ran this but I'm getting an error

```
name 'test_scores' is not defined
```

Comment: You need to define the array first, something like:

test_scores = [88,92,79,93,84]

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a = sign after test_scores
change `test_scores[88,92,79,93,84]` to `test_scores=[88,92,79,93,84]`